# Isomorphism between pairs of dual vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am trying to self-learn functional analysis via the book Topological Vector Spaces by Robertson and Robertson and I am stuck at the following which they state without proof.

This is stated on [page 35 of their book](https://books.google.com/books?id=mV44AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=topological+vector+spaces+dual+pairs+robertson+and+robertson&source=bl&ots=H5eOVYfOql&sig=w3JOHj-YGfihibTNR5EEUPTbCQw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=topological%20vector%20spaces%20dual%20pairs%20robertson%20and%20robertson&f=false). Linking first to page 32 where they define a dual pair.

Given vector space $E$, vector space $E'$ which is the space of continuous linear functionals on $E$, $E'^*$ which is the space of linear functionals on $E'$ and $F$ a vector space.

It is also given that $E\subseteq F\subseteq E'^*$ .

I am trying to prove that if $(E,E')$ is a dual pair, then $(E',F)$ is also a dual pair.

If I understand correctly given any two vector spaces, $E$ and $F$, $(E,F)$ is a dual pair if there is a linear bijection between $E$ and a subspace of $F^*$ and there is a linear bijection between $F$ and a subspace of $E^*$.

So, I need to show that there is a linear bijection from $F$ to a subspace of $E'^*$ and that there is a linear bijection from $E'$ to $F^*$.

Now, I know from the hypothesis that there is a linear bijection from $E$ to a subspace of $E'^*$ . To show that there exists a linear bijection from $F$ to some subspace of $E'^*$ , should I be using some sort of Hahn-Banach extension type theorem?

Showing that there is a bijection from $E'$ to some subspace of $F^*$ also seems a bit tricky. I know that there is a bijection from $E'$ to some subspace of $E^*$ . In general, if $E\subseteq F$, is it not the case that $F^* \subseteq E^*$ ? If yes, how can the required isomorphism be established between $E'$ and a subspace of $F^*$ ?

Thanks in advance for any help/pointer.

Comment: Well, by the definition you need a bilinear form on $E \times E'$ (and this induces a bijection). So start with a bilinear form, I would say.

Comment: You also need to identify $E$ with a space of functionals somehow, for the inclusion $E \subseteq F \subseteq E'^\ast$ to make sense, presumably via the canonical evaluation map? I cannot access all of the book.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thanks, I will try and see what a bilinear form buys me. Regarding canonical evaluation map, the book does not talk about it. It talks about a bipolar. I have uploaded page 35 where this is actually stated. http://imgur.com/9SEfps5 Thx for your help thus far.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I began with a bilinear form as you suggested, and here is how far I got. I essentially need to find a bilinear form $<x',y>$, where $x'\in E'$ and $y\in F$ that satisfy properties D and D' listed in the link in the page of my OP.I have defined it so that $<x',\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2>=\alpha<x',y_1>+\beta<x',y_2>$.  I have shown that $\forall x'\in E', \exists y\in F: <x',y>\neq 0$. I am stuck in proving the other property $\forall y\in F, \exists x'\in E': <x',y>\neq 0$. Do you have any thoughts on the way forward or whether my overall approach seems ok?